# FileNotFoundException on Java

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

i am trying to read the input of integers such as

```
17
100
19
18
```

on a .txt file, but i always get a FileNotFoundException. It will output the result

```
0000
```

if i run the code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class umm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("huhu.txt"));
        int [] tall = new int [100];
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
             tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
             System.out.print(tall[i]);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

if i add the integers in the .txt file so that it will have 6 integers like this

```
17
100
19
18
2
5
```

it will output

```
000000
```

doesn't this mean that the file exists and it can access it? but why does it keep saying FileNotFound?

Comment: Use the full path of the file not just *huhu.txt*

Comment: Well. Because the file isn't found. Ensure you locate the file at the right path. You can print the current path during execution by, e.g. `System.out.println(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
 tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
 System.out.print(tall[i]);
```

The array element you read is not the same as the one you print (you print the next one, because the `i++` has increased the index).

This explains all the 0 you get.

It is unclear to me how you get the `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path for huhu.txt.

You can see where your program is looking for huhu.txt by running this code.

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: i did this and changed the line into something like Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\eleanor\\workspace\\something\\huhu.txt")); but it is still giving me the FileNotFoundException though

Comment: nevermind, i got it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

thats because you print the next element in the array that is not yet affected 
,so try this

```
 while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
        tall[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(tall[i]);
        i++;
}
```